# taking the average of each person and then run a regression

Tags: regression, mean, dataset

I have a very large data frame with 14000 rows and 4 columns.
In the data frame, every Person (2000 in total) stated for one week,(one day has one row, so in total every person has 7 rows) how often they used the car to go to work.
This will be my dependent variable.
So one row is basically one day.
Additional to that I have the independent variables, age, temperature, precipitation, and km they drove.
I am thinking, do take the average values for every person, so that I will have a data frame with 2000 rows and then run a regression, as I am struggling with the huge data set.
And I find it extremely messy to look at the scatterplot and find any relationships.

Does this make sense or will I run into difficulties ?
Is there anything I need to take into consideration ?

Comment: 14000 should easily fit RAM of a computer and should not be a problem when doing linear regression. What exactly are you struggling with? You may be interested in reading about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy , TL;DR things "on average" may differ from the tinkgs when looking at them at more granual level.

Comment: Thank you! I ran multiple different types of regressions, but they all did not quite work out. I can't use linear Regression as my Residual Plot tells me that the residuals are not independent, so I thought this might be an easier way

Answer (score 4):

By averaging you may hide important day-of-week effects, and you will lose a small to moderate amount of statistical information otherwise, which will somewhat decrease power and precision.  This appears to be an application suited to a random effects model, i.e., random person-specific intercepts.   This assumes an equal correlation pattern, i.e., the correlation within person for days s and t where s $\neq$ t is the same no matter what s and t.

You're right, scatterplots are hard to read when the signal:noise ratio is small (low $R^2$).  You can plot trends though, using nonparametric smoothers or regression splines.  But this only helps with bivariate relationships.

Comment: Thank you a lot Sir Harrell, so I will try to use nonparametric smoothers and regression splines, however I have to admit that I do not know how to interpret the output of a regression spline, do you have any advice ? as well as that, are there any assumptions that need to be met when running a non linear regression ?

Comment: The [RMS Course Notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms) go into details.  You don't try to interpret individual coefficients but rather interpret the partial effect plot.